# in XCode objective-C game project, how to include a .swift file with constants delcared in it

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have a game in Objective-C and I have constant in it declared like this, in file `GameplayConstants.h`:

```
#ifndef GameplayConstants_h
#define GameplayConstants_h

static float REGULAR_TIME_PER_FRAME = 0.1f;

#endif /* GameplayConstants_h */
```

I am converting game to swift, so I want to convert one by one file to swift. In particular, I want this constant (`REGULAR_TIME_PER_FRAME`) converted to a swift file, to a constant variable in a swift file GameplayConstants.swift (rather than in the `GameplayConstants.h` file which it currently sits in now). What should I do? I set the `defines module` in configuration file to `YES`, and I included the file (with line `include GameplayConstants.swift`), but I have various errors. At the moment, error is:

```
"missing @end"
```

in HeroAnimationhelper.m file, which has code (partial code displayed):

```
#import "HeroAnimationHelper.h"
#import "HeroConstants.h"
#import "dealer-Swift.h"

@implementation HeroAnimationHelper

//#include "GameplayConstants.h"
#include "GameplayConstants.swift"
```

As you see, I'm replacing the original .h file with .swift file.

What else do I need to do to use swift constants in a objective-c class?

Comment: You do not use the #include preprocessor directive with Swift files. You just need to include the generated header that contains interfaces for Swift like this: #import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h". You can read the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-swift-into-objective-c for more details.

Comment: @ChristosKoninis I tried that too. Didn't work.

Comment: Did you read the Apple's guide? What exactly was the thing not working(specific errors etc.)? Please update your answer to include the steps you followed from the official guide and the errors/problems you faced, including a minimum reproducible example is very helpful.